# Select all content of a web page from Chrome and save to a text file using AppleScript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, automator

I'm creating an Automator workflow to cycle through all the tabs of a Google Chrome window and save the webpage on each tab to a text file.

```
    on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set windowList to every window
        repeat with theWindow in windowList
            set tabList to every tab in theWindow
            repeat with theTab in tabList
                select all
                copy selection
                set theTitle to title of theTab
                set theScript to "echo" & (selection as text) & "> $HOME/Desktop/tmp" & quoted form of POSIX path of theTitle & "-clipboard-file.txt"
                display dialog theScript
                do shell script theScript
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

However this generates empty text files.
I suspect that the "copy selection" does not interact with the system pasteboard. Is there a way I can copy the text into paste board or export directly to text files?

Answer (score 1):

[This has been **[edited]** to include the magic unicode-friendly "coercion". See the updated line under the "unicode-friendly" comment. The line uses the famous AppleEvent code *option-backslash* and *option-shift-backslash* characters]

It seems you just want the text, as if it were copied to the clipboard, saved to each file.
I would caution you about using the method you've started out with, only because there may be situations where no title leaves you with a file actually named ".txt", which would be invisible! So I'd say use a counting variable along with what you have, just in case (this worked on my machine and has a safeguard for untitled pages):

```
--first, I get the desktop as an old mac style path, using the Finder:
tell application "Finder" to set dt to desktop as string

tell application "Google Chrome"
    set windowList to every window
    set tabCount to 1
    repeat with theWindow in windowList
        set tabList to every tab in theWindow
        repeat with theTab in tabList
            set wHTMLText to execute theTab javascript "document.body.innerText;"
            set thetitle to title of theTab
            if thetitle is "" then set thetitle to ("untitled" & (tabCount as string))
            set filePath to (dt & "tmp:" & thetitle & ".txt")
            set myFile to open for access filePath with write permission
            --unicode-friendly:
            write wHTMLText to myFile as «class utf8»
            close access myFile
            set tabCount to tabCount + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

[EDIT:] Oh, and if you want the HTML, use "document.body.innerHTML;" and save with ".html" extension.

Comment: Thanks! This works by adding all the text, yet it does not support UTF-8. So non-ASCII characters are broken. How to specify encoding in the save action? Sorry I didn't ask a separate question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm noticing that the variable contains unicode, but when it saves it messes it up. I'm going to figure out a way...

Comment: Note the updated answer. I hope this works for you, @kakyo -- it seems to work for me.

Comment: By the way, @kakyo - if this works, please 'accept' the answer so we all know it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I took a little bit of a different approach.  This script works but I still can't figure out how to paste the items as a list

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    every window
    URL of every tab of item 1 of result
    set the clipboard to the result as text
end tell
do shell script "pbpaste > ~/Desktop/ClipboardFile.txt"
```